# Flutter load json response to List

Tags: json, flutter, api

This json response work fine with below List.

**[{"id":"1","ename":"KING","sal":"5000"**............

```
List<Emp> emp= (json.decode(response.body) as List)
        .map((data) => Emp.fromJson(data))
        .toList();
```

But how in list load data when on start json stay **items**

**{"items":[{"id":1,"ename":"KING","sal":5000............**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json.decode(response.body)['items']` instead of `json.decode(response.body)`

**An example:**

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  
  // sample body.response

  final j = '''{
  "items": [
  {"id":"1","ename":"KING","sal":"5000"},
  {"id":"2","ename":"KING","sal":"5000"}
  ]
  }''';

  List<Emp> emp = (json.decode(j)['items'] as List)
      .map((data) => Emp.fromJson(data))
      .toList();

  print(emp);
}

class Emp {
  String id;
  String ename;
  String sal;

  Emp({this.id, this.ename, this.sal});

  Emp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    ename = json['ename'];
    sal = json['sal'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['ename'] = this.ename;
    data['sal'] = this.sal;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Emp> emp= (json.decode(response.body)["items"] as List)
        .map((data) => Emp.fromJson(data))
        .toList();
```